# MySQL result set

Tags: mysql

Consider there is a table called employee in MySQL database.

If I use "select firstname from employee;"

The output will be

### firstname

xyz 
abv 
asd 
asdf

If I use "select FIRSTNAME from employee;"

The output will be

### FIRSTNAME

xyz 
abv 
asd 
asdf

But i need name of the attribute should be display in uppercase in the result of this query.

how to do it in wamp server?

Answer (score 1):

Use Mysql [UPPER](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-upper-function.php) to convert names to upper case

```
SELECT UPPER(name) AS FIRSTNAME
```

Comment: if we use upper(name), only data in the column will be convert into upper case. Still the attribute "firstname" will be display exactly how we use in the query.

Comment: then change the alias to upper case as well `FIRSTNAME`. Updated my post.

Comment: "FIRSTNAME" should be display only in uppercase even I use smaller cases for alias name.Expecting how it be in oracle.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the case in MySQL